# Allow Crosscompany selection only for one of two datasources in a form

Tags: join, datasource, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a form with two datasources (say DS1, DS2), both inner joined, and now I want only DS1 to select data crosscompany, but not DS2, is that possible?

I have already tried turning CrossCompanyAutoQuery to true, and also turning on the crosscompany selection in the datasource init() method, both did not work.

Comment: If this is an inner join, and one data source will selecting data from one company only, it will automatically limit data in the other data source to the same company, won't it? Can you clarify your scenario as I cannot imagine a scenario with an inner join where only one datasource should be crosscompany.

Comment: Scenario is that my client runs a customized form, where with every order they select/attach Saleorder invoices, now some of the companies are sister companies, so he wants Orders shown only from Company1, but when he goes to attach the invoices, he wants invoices from Company1 as well as company 2, there are two datasources, one for the orders, other of invoices, i want only invoices to have crosscompany data, both are innerjoined